# Execute Update Always SET Found to FALSE

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, insert-update

I have wrote following trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tbl_scdr_insert_trigger() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
<< fk >>
DECLARE
    rowcount int;
    myrec RECORD;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'UPDATE sc_'|| to_char(NEW.start_datetime, 'YYYY_MM') ||' SET a = a + ($1).a, b = b + ($1).b WHERE (e_id = ($1).e_id AND start_datetime = ($1).start_datetime AND c_id = ($1).c_id'
    USING NEW;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS rowcount = ROW_COUNT;
    RAISE NOTICE 'found %', rowcount;
    IF not found THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'not found';
    ELSIF found THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'found';
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When Ever Called this always return Zero as Rowcount because statement is not committed Yet and Found is always False even there are records with same values of where clause columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-statements.html) states:

> EXECUTE changes the output of GET DIAGNOSTICS, but does not change FOUND

That means that FOUND will always be FALSE in your case, because you are using EXECUTE and not a static UPDATE statement.

Comment: I have read this document and there is no explicit statement about Execute Update but why rowcount is always Zero. since trigger works on single transaction and can not commit it.

Comment: The transaction does not matter in that case. You should have proper diagnostics right after executing the query. Can you assign the entire query string to a variable, then raise it as a notice, and then execute that UPDATE in the console and see whether it actually updates something?